# Can't get JLabel with inline HTML to center with BoxLayout

Tags: java, layout, jlabel

I'm attempting to horizontally center a JLabel that contains inline HTML, but I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried manually centering it, but had no luck.

Here's what it looks like for me:

[image]

Full class code:

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Client extends JFrame{
    private final String url = "http://example.com/";
    public Client() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(200, 225);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        addComponents(mainPanel);
        add(mainPanel);

        setTitle(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public void addComponents(JPanel pane) {
        Button btn1 = new Button("1");
        btn1.setSize(200, 50);
        btn1.setFocusable(false);
        pane.add(btn1);

        Button btn2 = new Button("2");
        btn2.setSize(200, 50);
        btn2.setFocusable(false);
        pane.add(btn2);

        Button btn3 = new Button("3");
        btn3.setSize(200, 50);
        btn3.setFocusable(false);
        pane.add(btn3);

        JLabel lblWebsite = new JLabel("<html><a href=\"" + url + "\">Visit lblAbout1</a></html>", BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
        lblWebsite.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        lblWebsite.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(url));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        pane.add(lblWebsite);   
    }
}
```

Comment: It will work `mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));`

Comment: @Braj http://i.imgur.com/HBkSsmn.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [JComponent#setAlignmentX()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setAlignmentX%28float%29) method

Enclose the anchor inside a `div` that is aligned to center.

```
JLabel lblWebsite = new JLabel("<html><div align='center'><a href=\"" + url + "\">Visit lblAbout1</a></div></html>", BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
lblWebsite.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
```

Snapshots:

[image]

Comment: It will work in both the cases either `GridLauout` or `BoxLayout`